# quick sort using partitioning technique

Tags: c++, algorithm

I implemented quick sort using partitioning technique. The one issue I am facing is based on the pivot I need to change my code. Below is my implementation of qsort.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void qsort1(int arr[], int p, int q)
{ 
    if(p<q)
    {
        int ppos = p;
        int pivot = arr[ppos];
        int r = p; 
        for(int i=p;i<=q;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i] < pivot)
            {
                r++;
                swap(arr[i],arr[r]);  
            }
        }
        swap(arr[r],arr[ppos]);
        qsort1(arr,p,r-1);
        qsort1(arr,r+1,q);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[]= {9,7,4,1,2,3};
    qsort1(arr,0,5);
    for(int i =0;i<6;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

To change the pivot from first to last element I need to change my r to exclude the last element. can someone please suggest me a better implementation using same partitioning technique . By the way its not a homework question.

Comment: If it's not homework question, please use `std::sort`...

Comment: I've you're including `<iostream>`, then this is not a C program. I've edited your tags.

Comment: @KennyTM  Im preparing for interviews

Comment: @KennyTM There are about 1000 reasons I can think of not to use STL in every case. With that said, most people lack basic understanding of how algorithms work, and if mousey is doing "self homework" then I think he should be praised

Comment: @mousey generally speaking, you should use a randomly chosen initial qsort pivot. For instance if your array is already sorted using this pivot selection method it will cause O(n * n) behavior. Choosing a random elements helps to amortize the worst-case cost of O(n*n) to roughly O(n log n). Failing a random element, choosing the middle pivot or even the median (if you have access to that) works too.

Comment: @OrgnlDave I am planning to implement randomized quick sort. But the issue Im am facing is that based on the pivot may be first, last or random I need to change my code for each and different pivot. The same code that I posted above doesnt work for last element as pivot. I need some help coming up with a better implementation.

Comment: Given that you fold everything into one function rather than having `partition()` in a separate function I guess I would query the rationale: I can't cope with code as complex as this! On the other hand sorting seems to be unnecessary complex for an interview given that most people seem to be incapable of writing a single line of code if they can't copy it from somewhere...

Answer (score 4):

Why not just swap the first element w/ the one you want to use as the pivot?  Then your code using the first element as the pivot will do just fine.

Comment: +1: Make a small change [processing] and reduce the problem to the already solved one.

Comment: This is a good example of http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal